# Typescript OR in Function Intake

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I am trying to tell my function to accept either a string or a custom type

```
onPress: (value: string | CustomType)=>void
```

however when I assign it a string or CustomType the compiler yells at me with `is not assignable to type '(value: string | CustomType ) => void'`

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me, that you are mistaken regarding the type of your `onPress` variable. It is not of type `string | CustomType`, but of type `(value: string | CustomType) => void`. That type represents a function that takes a single argument of type `string` or `CustomType` and does not return anything.

You could assign an existing function to `onPress`:

```ts
type CustomType = number  // just for testing purposes
let onPress: (value: string | CustomType) => void

function doSomething(value: string | CustomType) {
  console.log("Doing something here with value " + value)
}

onPress = doSomething

onPress("BY432")
```

Or you could assign it an anonymous function:

```ts
type CustomType = number  // just for testing purposes
let onPress: (value: string | CustomType) => void

onPress = function (value) {
  console.log("Doing something here with value " + value)
}

onPress("BY432")
```

Or you could assign it an arrow function (also anonymous):

```ts
type CustomType = number  // just for testing purposes
let onPress: (value: string | CustomType) => void

onPress = value => console.log("Doing something here with value " + value)

onPress("BY432")
```